# Pyspark nested loop in the same DataFrame. How to iterate?

Tags: loops, dataframe, join, pyspark, nested

**EDIT**. **TL;DR:**
I'm trying to achieve a nested loop in a pyspark Dataframe. As you may see,I want the nested loop to start from the NEXT row (in respect to the first loop) in every iteration, so as to reduce unneccesary iterations. Using Python , I can use **[row.Index+1:]** . Generally, in plain Python I can achieve that with the next code:

```
r=1000
joins=[]
for row in df.itertuples():
    for k in df[row.Index+1:].itertuples():
        a = np.array((row.x, row.y))
        b = np.array((k.x, k.y))
        if row.class!= k.class:
            if row.x < k.x+r:
                if np.linalg.norm(a-b) < r:
                    joins.append((row.name, k.name))
print(joins)
```

How I can achieve the same result in Spark?

**Long problem analysis**:
I have a list

```
people=[('john', 35, 54, 'A'), ('george', 94, 84, 'B'), ('nicolas', 7, 9, 'B'), ('tom', 86, 93, 'A'), ('jason', 62, 73, 'B'), ('bill', 15, 58, 'A'), ('william', 9, 3, 'A'), ('brad', 73, 37, 'B'), ('cosmo', 52, 67, 'B'), ('jerry', 73, 30, 'A')]
```

and I convert it to a spark Dataframe which I sort it by 'y', descending:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('x', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('y', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('class', StringType(), True),
])
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(people)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
df.orderBy('y',ascending=False).show()
```

```
+-------+---+---+-----+
|   name|  x|  y|class|
+-------+---+---+-----+
|    tom| 86| 93|    A|
| george| 94| 84|    B|
|  jason| 62| 73|    B|
|  cosmo| 52| 67|    B|
|   bill| 15| 58|    A|
|   john| 35| 54|    A|
|   brad| 73| 37|    B|
|  jerry| 73| 30|    A|
|nicolas|  7|  9|    B|
|william|  9|  3|    A|
+-------+---+---+-----+
```

What I 'm looking for is to Join 'class A' names with 'class B' names, when a condition is fulfilled. Let's say for example , when Euclidean distance (A item - B item) < 10.
I believe that cross join is not the best idea because it could be time consuming with large datasets.

I think it would be nice if I could iterate.
pseudocode:

```
start with row1
if row1[class] != row2[class]:
    if row1['y'] - row2['y'] < 10:
        if Euclidean distance(row1.item - row2.item) < 10:
            join row1.name, row2.name
        end
    else break

it keeps iterating until row1['y'] - row['y'] >= 10

then a new iteration starts from row2
if row2[class] != row3[class]:
    etc etc
```

In that way, there will be fewer checks between different rows.
Which is opposite to cross join where everything is checked against everything resulting in larger execution times.
But how can this be done in spark?
Any ideas?

edit. Required output (in any form):

```
brad, jerry
```

(The only pair that its items belong to different classes & their euclidean distance is 7, which is lower than 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you could split the dataframe into two dataframes based on the `class` column, then join them based on specified the join clause (using outer join):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, struct
A_df = df.where(col('class') == 'A').withColumnRenamed('name', 'A.name')
B_df = df.where(col('class') == 'B').withColumnRenamed('name', 'B.name')

join_clause = A_df.y - B_df.y <= 10
result = A_df.join(B_df, join_clause, 'outer')
```

And with the result dataframe, convert the two columns to one list column:

```
result = result.withColumn(collect_list(struct(col('A.name'), col('B.name')))
```

**Update**

Here's an implementation of something using `mapPartitions`, no joins or converting to DataFrame:

```
import math

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def process_data(rows):
    r = 1000
    joins = []
    for row1 in rows:
        for row2 in rows:
            if row1['class'] != row2['class']:
                if row1['x'] < row2['x'] + r:
                    if math.sqrt((row1['x'] - row2['x']) ** 2 + (row1['y'] - row2['y']) ** 2) <= r:
                        joins.append((row1['name'], row2['name']))
    return joins


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()

people = [('john', 35, 54, 'A'),
          ('george', 94, 84, 'B'),
          ('nicolas', 7, 9, 'B'),
          ('tom', 86, 93, 'A'),
          ('jason', 62, 73, 'B'),
          ('bill', 15, 58, 'A'),
          ('william', 9, 3, 'A'),
          ('brad', 73, 37, 'B'),
          ('cosmo', 52, 67, 'B'),
          ('jerry', 73, 30, 'A')]

fields = ('name', 'x', 'y', 'class')

data = [dict(zip(fields, person)) for person in people]

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

result = rdd.mapPartitions(process_data).collect()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('tom', 'jason'), ('cosmo', 'jerry')]
```

***Update 2***

Added an initial sort step on the 'y' field, repartition to ensure all data is on one partition (so all records can be compared), and changed the nested loop:

```
import math

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def process_data(rows):
    r = 1000
    joins = []
    rows = list(rows)
    for i, row1 in enumerate(rows):
        for row2 in rows[i:]:
            if row1['class'] != row2['class']:
                if row1['x'] < row2['x'] + r:
                    if math.sqrt((row1['x'] - row2['x']) ** 2 + (row1['y'] - row2['y']) ** 2) < r:
                        joins.append((row1['name'], row2['name']))
    return joins


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()

people = [('john', 35, 54, 'A'),
          ('george', 94, 84, 'B'),
          ('nicolas', 7, 9, 'B'),
          ('tom', 86, 93, 'A'),
          ('jason', 62, 73, 'B'),
          ('bill', 15, 58, 'A'),
          ('william', 9, 3, 'A'),
          ('brad', 73, 37, 'B'),
          ('cosmo', 52, 67, 'B'),
          ('jerry', 73, 30, 'A')]

fields = ('name', 'x', 'y', 'class')

data = [dict(zip(fields, person)) for person in people]

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

result = rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x['y'], ascending=False).repartition(1).mapPartitions(process_data).collect()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('william', 'nicolas'), ('william', 'brad'), ('william', 'cosmo'), ('william', 'jason'), ('william', 'george'), ('nicolas', 'jerry'), ('nicolas', 'john'), ('nicolas', 'bill'), ('nicolas', 'tom'), ('jerry', 'brad'), ('jerry', 'cosmo'), ('jerry', 'jason'), ('jerry', 'george'), ('brad', 'john'), ('brad', 'bill'), ('brad', 'tom'), ('john', 'cosmo'), ('john', 'jason'), ('john', 'george'), ('bill', 'cosmo'), ('bill', 'jason'), ('bill', 'george'), ('cosmo', 'tom'), ('jason', 'tom'), ('george', 'tom')]
```

Comment: As I mention, I would prefer not to use Joins, because they check every A.item against every B.item. I'm searching of a solution like in the pseudocode that I posted, so as to reduce checks and execution time. I would like to iterate row1 against the next rows until "row1.y - row2.y < 10" clause fails. Then iterate row2 against next rows etc. Also, when the aforementioned clause is fulfilled, a second (complete Euclidean distance) will be computed.

Comment: I added a simpler take on my probem. You can find it at the start of my post. I give the Python code of the iteration. I just want to achieve the same in Spark

Comment: Check out my update - is that a better approach/more along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: This is better but it misses something: What is important is that the nested loop to start from the NEXT row of the first loop at every iteration. In python we can achieve that by `for k in df[row.Index+1:].itertuples():` . How can we syntax that now?

Comment: Also, something else must also be wrong, as for r=1000, every pair should be joined based on Euclidean distance.

Comment: And also, I wanted the data to be sorted by 'y' descending, so as to get advantage of my logic of iteration.

Comment: Added another update! Let me know if this captures the idea better.

Comment: I believe this is what I asked for!Of course,one note,to be perfect, the sorting by 'y' should be desceding,could you please also add this last touch,so as to mark it as correct?And one question, generally is it normal that that iteration is a lot slower than the outer (or cross) join function? Join functions is generally the best way to go in Spark? I hoped that I could find a faster solution,because I was afraid that when we use outer/cross joins, everything is checked against everything and so it would be a slow procedure.But if I can understand correctly,simple Joins is what should we use?

Comment: Done! Set the `ascending` flag to False in the `sortBy` function (by default, it's True) under Update 2. And typically, yes - while join functions are expensive, they are optimized and will almost always be faster than an explicit iterative approach. In fact, if you're interested, you can review the DAGs in the Spark UI (`localhost:4040` if you run locally) and compare the two approaches. Best of luck, and accept my answer when you get the chance!